# Container of pointers Issue

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, stl, exc-bad-access

I have classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and the following hierarchy:

```
class A {
    B* b;
};

class B {
    C<D>* c;
};

template <class T>
class C<T> {
    list<T*> ds;
};

class D {
};
```

I allocate `A` first as an `A*` member inside a base class, using `new A()`. Within `A` I allocate `b` using `new B()`. Within `B` I allocate `c` using `new C<D>()`.

As soon as I attempt to call `ds.size()` the program crashes. An `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` arises inside `ds` when it tries to call its `begin()` method within `size()`.

Do you know why this would happen? I've been using C++ for a few years but this is my first foray into using pointers within standard containers, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This isn't enough code to diagnose the problem. Also use a debugger to be sure that the code segfaults _inside_ the `list` code, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Provide a testcase that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: So I take it there's theoretically nothing wrong with this structuring, it should be ok? Just knowing that I'm not missing something obvious helps.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's nothing "wrong". If nothing else, IMO it's so complex and unintuitive as to be a design smell.

Comment: It's not unintuitive for me, and if you saw the actual classes you'd be reassured. It's been engineered to optimise OpenGL performance by avoiding copying, and allows a highly flexible render management hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, to my knowledge, should not care one way or another what the contents of list ds are.  When you insert elements into containers and things like that you need to ensure that your element type supports all the necessary functionality (i.e. its assignable, copyable, and has the correct functions within it depending on which are required within that container class' members).

The .size function should just return the value of an internal member though, it doesn't make much sense for that to be the thing that is crashing.  Are you sure everything was properly allocated in your real code? it sounds to me like you just have an uninitialied pointer somewhere in the call-chain.

Comment: Ok this is the reassurance I was looking for, thanks w00te. I'll investigate my code further and post whatever I find here.

Comment: Ah problem solved - I was calling a superclass constructor which called a virtual method overridden in the subclass, but properties required within the overridden method hadn't yet been created in the subclass constructor :)

Comment: Sounds about right.  It's surprisingly easily to de-reference a null when you start playing around with inheritance in complex classes.  Happy you found it so quick :)

Answer (score 0):

But I think the member `b` of class `A` is default which is `private`. Maybe it cause the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.